# How to grab column value from ADLS gen 2 csv file and use the column value in the body of the email,also send blob data as attachment to outlook mail

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-app-standard

Here is my Scenario,
There will be a drop of csv file into blob storage every day ,that will be processed by my dataflow in ADF and generate a csv in output folder.

Now Using logic apps, I need to send that csv file (less than 10 mb ) as an attachement to customer via Outlook connector.
Besides ,My body of the email must have dynamic value coming from that blob csv .
For example 'AppWorks' is the column value in column 'Works/not'. Sometimes it may be "AppNotWorks".So How to handle this scenario in Azure logic apps

Comment: So, you want to send mail for each separate row where body would be the value of the column `Works/not`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For example i have a csv file in blob .I need to attach that file as an mail attachment via Outlook and also in the body of the Mail , I need to access the "CustomerName" Column Value which is changing on a daily basis but its only one similar value .

Comment: Example : Body of my mail:  Hi [CustomerName] , Random description .

Comment: So, the entire column has same value which changes daily. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combination of both data factory and logic apps to do this. Use `look up` activity to get the first row of the file (Since the entire column value will be same, we can get the required value from one row).

[image]

- Now use web activity to trigger the logic app. Pass the logic app's HTTP request URL to web activity. In the body, pass the following dynamic content:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow
```

[image]

- When you debug the pipeline, the logic app will be successfully triggered. I have given the Request Body JSON schema to get values individually. For the sample I have taken, it would look as shown below:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "customer": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

- Create a connection to storage account to link the required file.

[image]

- Now, using the Outlook connector, send the Email.

[image]

- The following is the entire Logic app JSON:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmZGF0YSUyZnNhbXBsZTEuY3N2'))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmZGF0YSUyZnNhbXBsZTEuY3N2": "/data/sample1.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Attachments": [
                            {
                                "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))}",
                                "Name": "sample1.csv"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Body": "<p>Hi @{triggerBody()?['customer']},<br>\n<br>\nRandom description</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "sample data",
                        "To": "<to_email>"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "customer": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westus2/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/v-sarikontha-Mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westus2/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- The following is the resulting Mail image for reference:

[image]